# use of "one of "

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, grammatical-number

Which of these sentences is correct and why?

> 1) One of his notable works is *Swami and his friends*.
>
> 2) One of his notable work is *Swami and his friends*.
>
> 3) One of his notable works are *Swami and his friends*.

Answer (score 2):

Number 1 is correct. You should also italicize titles. Also, it appears that the English title of the novel omits the word "his".

> One of his notable works is *Swami and Friends*.

@LittleEva explains why you should use "works" and not "work" in a comment:

> One of [more than one]

There is more than one work. So you should use the plural.

You should use "is" and not "are" because *Swami and Friends* is the name of one book, not many, even though "friends" is plural in the title.